# android firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase-android, firebase, firebaseanalytics

android firebase Analytics, Подключил Firebase Analytics, как подсчитать  сколько раз пользователь кликнул по той новой или иной кнопке, по каким экранам переходил, док не понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналитика через Firebase красивая и легко подключаемая но да - плохо документированная и сильно обрезанная по фичам.

Единственный нормальный найденный мной способ - посылка события `select_content` с параметром `content_type`.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "value"));
FirebaseAnalytics analitics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
analitics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, args);
```

Это событие с этим типом будет отображаться в консоли. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот свои ключи со своими ключами параметров для своих значений лично у меня не получилось сделать. Приходится пользоваться имеющимися в SDK и наугад подбирать к ним пары.